# Error message even after installing react-native on a clean project

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I installed Firebase using `npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app` and configured it, but I still have errors, even by having a clean project

```js
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.72.3",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0"
}
```

The error message:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module @react-native-firebase/database from D:\codes\react-native\gonsCafe\App.js: @react-native-firebase/database could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  1 | import * as React from "react";
  2 | import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
  3 | import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';                      
  4 | // import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
  5 | // import AllScreens from "./screens/AllScreens";
  6 | import { firebaseConfig } from "./config";
```

Comment: Could you show, in your question, the error message you're getting? Because there's not that much anyone could help without a error message.

Comment: Answered your question! Don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted answer if it does solve your question! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage), you need to install both react-native `app` and `database` modules, as follows:

```bash
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/database
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app
```

If you're developing for IOS too, run this on a macOS system:

```bash
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
```

Then, you import the module as you just did.

```js
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
```

Comment: I already install it npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app  and still shows the error on importing now I have installed the database too now the error for "import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";" have gone looks like both packages or required

Comment: Yup, both are required